How to code SIMULINK to add functions connected in series and subtract them when connected in parallel?
Without having to write separate functions for adding and subtracting.
I am a beginner trying to learn MATLAB and I want to make custom function blocks that can be connected in series or parallel but the arithmetics performed on them are not necessarily the same as that done in electrical circuits.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
